# Append a "layer" to 3D-Array with Numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array with dimensions `12 x 12 x 4`. Now I'm trying to add an extra layer to this cube resulting in a `12 x 13 x 4` array. This 13th layer should contain the corresponding indices from the first axis, so for example addressing `[7, 13, :]` results in `[7, 7, 7, 7]`.

Hard to explain but maybe someone has some advice on how to achieve this with numpy?

EDIT:
I've found a solution, though it seems a little overcomplicated:

```
# Generate extra layer
layer = np.repeat(np.arange(0, 12)[:, np.newaxis], data.shape[2], axis=1)

# Get dimensions right...
layer = np.expand_dims(layer, axis=1)

# ... and finally append to data
result = np.append(data, layer, axis=1)
```

Still open for better suggestions.

Comment: Use `concatenate`.  But be careful about dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea.  A slight simplification:

```
layer = np.repeat(np.arange(3)[:,None,None], data.shape[2], axis=2)
result = np.concatenate((data, layer), axis=1)
```